# How to read an UCS-2 text-file as an UTF-8 string, in PHP?

Tags: php, string, utf-8, ucs2

I have an UCS-2 text files. Now, I want to read this text file as an UTF-8 string. I have used this code for doing it.

**my_code.php**:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);        
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><p><input type="file" name="my_file" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="+" /><hr />';

$my_str = file_get_contents(($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name']));
echo $my_str;

?>
```

**viet_test.txt**:

```
"Vietnamese" is "Tiếng Việt".
```

But, it returns **wrong**: `��"Vietnamese" is "Ti�ng Vi�t".`. There is what I am looing for: `"Vietnamese" is "Tiếng Việt"` (in UTF-8).

Can you tell me: "What is wrong in my code? And, how to fix it?".

---

I am sorry, I am not very professional in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read the file "as UTF-8". It contains UCS-2, so reading it you'll read a UCS-2 string. You can however *convert* the read UCS-2 string to UTF-8:

```
$my_str = file_get_contents($_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name']);
$my_str = mb_convert_encoding($my_str, 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2');
echo $my_str;
```

Note that you might have to use `UCS-2BE` or `UCS-2LE` explicitly.
If that still returns "nothing", you have a different problem than anything to do with encodings.

Comment: If you have to "determine" it, you're already in an uncomfortable situation. You should *know* what encoding what is in. You can use `mb_detect_encoding($my_str, array('UCS-2LE', 'UCS2-BE', 'UCS-2'))`.